# Firebase database current year items query

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I'm having an issue when trying to get all of the WorkDays from the current year, but I get every WorkDay item. Is there a different way to do this (without retrieving all of the WorkDays and filtering them), or am I missing something doing it this way?

**My function for retrieving the workdays for the current year:**

```
fun getWorkDays(mAuth: FirebaseAuth) {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        val user = mAuth.currentUser
        val userId = user!!.uid
        val currentYear = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR)
        val startDate = "$currentYear-01-01"
        val endDate = "$currentYear-12-31"

        val reference =
            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(userId)
                .child("WorkDays")

        reference.orderByChild("postedAtDate")
            .startAt(startDate)
            .endBefore(endDate)
            .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {
                override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                    var workDays = mutableListOf<WorkDay>()
                    for (postSnapshot in snapshot.children) {
                        val workDay = postSnapshot.getValue(WorkDay::class.java)
                        workDays.add(workDay!!)
                    }
                    this@ReportsViewModel._workDays.value = ArrayList(workDays)
                }

                override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                    _errorMessage.postValue(error.message.toString())
                }
            })
    }
}
```

**Data at /Users/WorkDays**

```
"WorkDays": {
    "-NROXAA_d6lGc19BQ9Pk": {
      "date": "Saturday, 25.03.2023.",
      "hours": "5",
      "month": "03",
      "postedAtDate": "2023-03-25"
    },
    "-NROXCcAZmORQh95V8hi": {
      "date": "Saturday, 25.03.2023.",
      "hours": "6",
      "month": "04",
      "postedAtDate": "2023-03-25"
    },
    "-Oo_nq-g64JRM1cThb3q": {
      "date": "Wednesday, 25.03.2026.",
      "hours": "8",
      "month": "07",
      "postedAtDate": "2026-03-25"
    }
  }
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show the data at `/Users/WorkDays` in your database (as text, no screenshots please). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: There i Added it

Comment: The code looks fine to me at first glance (aside from an off-by-one-error in `endDate`, but I doubt that is the problem), and matches the data structure. Can you change the code to use hard-coded values for the start and end value, and print the `postedAtDate`, and then show us the updated code and its output?

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information Frank asked for, and please also respond using @.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen the problem was that when I change the date on the phone Firebase just won't respond to my requests. Thanks for trying to help.

Comment: Hey @FarisRizvanović. Does that mean you got it working now? If so, can you post what you changed (including the code) as an answer below, so that others can benefit from it? If not, can you post the update I asked for in your question?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen when I was testing it I was going a year forward on the android emulator which caused the firebase request not to go through, but as soon as I put the date in the emulator's settings back to the current date and time it worked. I tested it by adding dummy data for previous years (while the phone is set to the current date and time) and I got the data only from the current year which means it worked. So what I got out of this is "Firebase won't respond to your request if your date and time are not set to the current date time for some reason".Dont know is it just me or firbase